# JavaScript menus broken in main site?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, javascript

I am getting this JS error in my browser console:

```
TypeError: e.attr(...) is undefined
```

on the StackOverflow homepage, in this file, line 82:

```
http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=6c690b307479
```

This has the effect that the two pop-up menus at the top of the page no longer work. Meta SO seems to be unaffected.

Firefox 19.0.2, OS X 10.6.8 (though Safari seems affected too, so I suspect a JS bug).

Comment: I believe this has now been fixed.

Comment: @balpha: thanks for looking into it. I'll ping this thread if I see it again, but I suppose it could have been a corrupted, cached JS asset.